# Stop Service with NSIS

Tags: service, admin, nsis

In my NSIS script I want to stop the fax service. I'm using the services plugin and the service fails to stop.
I use the admin mode.

```
services::SendServiceCommand 'stop' 'fax'
```

Comment: It would be really helpful in the future that you tell us that you are using a unofficial fork!

Answer (score 0):

Because you posted the same question on the NSIS forum I now know that you are using the Unicode fork.

The [services plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Services_plug-in) you are using does not support Unicode. You could try using the [CallAnsiPlugin plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CallAnsiPlugin_plug-in) on it but I would recommend that you use one of the [other service scripts/plugins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_do_I_start/stop/create/remove/check_a_service%3F): [NSIS Service Lib](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Service_Lib)

Answer (score 0):

ExecWait '$SYSDIR\net.exe stop ServiceName'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).